# When connecting to multiple databases, do I need multiple SQLAlchemy Metadata, Base, or Session objects?

Tags: python, mysql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a SQLAlchemy app that needs to connect to a PostgreSQL database and a MySQL database. Basically I'm loading the data from an existing MySQL database, doing some transforms on it, and then saving it in PostgreSQL.

I am managing the PostgreSQL schema using SQLAlchemy's `declarative base`. The MySQL database already exists, and I am accessing the schema via SQLAlchemy's reflection. Both have very different schemas.

I know I need dedicated `engines` for each database, but I'm unclear on whether I need dedicated objects of any of the following:

1. `Base` - I think this corresponds to the database schema. Since both databases have very different schemas, I will need a dedicated `Base` for each schema.
2. `Metadata` - Is this intended to be a single global metadata object that holds all schemas from all engines?
3. `Sessions` - I'm not sure, but I think I need separate sessions for each database? Or can a single `session` share multiple `engine`/`Base` combos? I'm using `scoped_sessions`.

Part of my confusion comes from not understanding the difference between `Base` and `Metadata`. The [SQLAlchemy docs say](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#module-sqlalchemy.schema):

> MetaData is a container object that keeps together many different features of a database (or multiple databases) being described.

This seems to imply that a single `metadata` can hold multiple `Base`'s, but I'm still a bit fuzzy on how that works. For example, I want to be able to call `metadata.create_all()` and create tables in PostgreSQL, but not MySQL.

Comment: Have a look at http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/, it answers many of your questions, though a bit long read. It doesn't mean you have to have a routing session, but it shows that you can.

Comment: the short answer is yes, you'll need separate instances of each of the above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that it's easiest to have separate instances of them all for both databases. It is possible to create a single [routing session](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2012/01/11/django-style-database-routers-in-sqlalchemy/), but it has its caveats.

The `sessionmaker` and `Session` also support [passing multiple *binds* as an argument](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.binds) and [2-phase commits](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_transaction.html#enabling-two-phase-commit), which can also allow using a single session with multiple databases. As luck would have it, the 2 databases that support 2-phase commits are PostgreSQL and MySQL.

About the relation between `Base` and `metadata`:

[`Base`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base) is a base class that has a metaclass used to declaratively create `Table` objects from information provided in the class itself and its subclasses. All `Table` objects implicitly declared by subclasses of `Base` will share the same `MetaData`.

You can provide *metadata* as an argument when creating a new declarative base and thus share it between multiple `Base`s, but in your case it is not useful.

[`MetaData`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData)
 is a collection of `Table` objects and their associated schema constructs. It also can hold a binding to an `Engine` or `Session`.

In short, you can have `Table`s and `MetaData` without a `Base`, but a `Base` requires `MetaData` to function.